# WCF Caching Strategy - Including Dependancies

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I would like to ask people's opinion on methods and strategies for introducing Caching to WCF.  In  particular what i am most interested in, is injected SQL Cache Dependencies.  Once a web application is copied to multiple application servers I want to synchronize the cache efficiently.

I am currently looking at the WCF Rest Starter Kit which introduces a nice WebCache attribute for OperationContracts in which you can add SqlCacheDependancies.

I am just interested and would be greateful for, others take or experience in tackling this problem.

Kind Regards,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which problem you're addressing, but you mention cache consistency across multiple servers.  Having run a SqlCacheDependency configuration previously, here's my take on it.

The SqlCacheDependency incorporated with the WebCache attribute is the same cache dependency implementation that's been available since .Net 2.0.  Overall, I find the aggregate configuration/operation/monitoring for SqlCacheDependency onerous.  The design is acceptable for a single cache, but multiple systems -- no thanks.

I like separation of concerns.  When working with multiple servers, I find a distributed cache tier much easier to manage than the SqlCacheDependency operation.  Plenty of open-source and commercial distributed cache providers available.  I find Memcache to be the most effective and operationally sound.